# Flutter scroll animation issue, I want image zoom animation when scrolling horizontally

Tags: flutter, animation, scroll, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

How to get image zoom animation when scrolling horizontally like this photo, scroll to the left and when I scroll the first image that pops out of the screen is enlarged and the next image is replaced

[image: the image]

Answer (score 1):

You can user this package for iamge slider it will automatically make center ( selected image bigger then other [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)

and for zooming and other image function use can user [photo_view](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view)